# Is it possible to get url of clicked link in WebEngineView?

Tags: qt, qml, qtwebengine, qt5.6

I've noticed that in Qt version 5.4, WebView has a signal named [navigationRequired](http://www.qutebrowser.org/tmp/qtdoc-featureperm/qml-qtwebkit-webview.html#onNavigationRequested-signal), which had a clicked URL in parameters. In the new WebView and WebEngineView, there is no such signal. I also haven't found any alternatives.

Is there any way to get a clicked link's URL in Qt 5.6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reimplement the method `acceptNavigationRequest` of `QWebEnginePage` :

```
class MyQWebEnginePage : public QWebEnginePage
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MyQWebEnginePage(QObject* parent = 0) : QWebEnginePage(parent){}

    bool acceptNavigationRequest(const QUrl & url, QWebEnginePage::NavigationType type, bool)
    {
        if (type == QWebEnginePage::NavigationTypeLinkClicked)
        {
            // retrieve the url here
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
};
```

Comment: So basically on every click in QML WebEngineView this method will be called?

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: sorry for such delayed question, but how do I use it? I mean, this is c++ class and I need to check it from qml.

Comment: Oh ok. Then see this link : http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtwebengine-webengineview.html#WebAction-prop. There are different actions that you can retrieve from your WebEngineView

Comment: Yes, indeed! Actions solve my problem. I just called WebEngineView.onLoadingChanged and checked whether loadRequest.status equals to LoadStartedStatus, and if so I called WebAction(Stop) and made a call from default browser.